# VB6 App - FileCopy Fails in Win7

Tags: vb6

We are currently in the final throes of testing our existing application before we begin the process of migrating the company over to 32-bit Windows 7 with Office 2010.
One of the remaining applications was written in VB6, and is experiencing a problem when it gets to perform a filecopy action.
Currently, it writes data to a file called MIDNSPTEMP.$$$ and when finished, uses the FileCopy command to copy it to an existing file called MIDNSP.$$$, where it gives me a Permission denied error. The next line which deletes the MIDNSPTEMP.$$$ is never hit.
If I create a new file in the same folder manually, that works, and I can also delete a file.
Can anyone point me at why it gives me a permission denied in this situation? VB6 is not a language that I am very familiar but no-one else is available to look at this.
Thanks in advance
Martin

Comment: Waht folder? I expect you're using a folder you don't have permissions to write to (The error message kinds gives that away :)

Comment: It's a network folder that I can write to and delete from, which is what threw me in the first place. I addd in a check to see if the files were closed properly, but it seems that they aren't closing which I'm guessing may be why I'm getting permission denied?

Comment: It could be, depends on your code that opens and closes them.
Does your process still have them open? tcarvin's reply should help you tell. Until we see soem code, we can;t give a definite answer.

Comment: In simple terms, I have a FelxGrid control, and when a user double clicks on an entry, it opens the associated file in TextPad. Details are logged into a file, taking either the last line of the existing file or adding new details, and then the files are closed. Code to open the temporary file is `Open Datadir + csNspTempFile For Output As #3`, whereas the code to open the file being read is `Open Datadir + csNspFile For Input As #2`. Each file is then closed using `Close #2` and `Close #3` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 does not automatically run commands as an administrative user like it did in XP instead they are run with the least privlege.  You will need to either grant less restrictive permissions to the folder where you are working or start the application as an administrator using run-as.

Comment: Ah that would be why then! Thanks for that - this application is called within another, so unless it can be run-as in code, I'll have to look at granting, as you suggest, less restrictive permissions. Thanks. Martin

Comment: Actually, am not sure if that is right...I have just done a copy x, y in Command Prompt in the same folder and it let me. The same application can write to other folders at a higher level, and to change the permissions would be a huge job. It looks more like the files are not being closed properly to me, but without changing the code I'm not sure what else I can do to resolve this.

Comment: Note that when you're running in the development environment, it's the permissions of the interpreter (VB98.exe) that apply, not those of your current working directory.  This can explain why, for example, a FileCopy can work fine as part of a compiled program, yet fail when run in the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the file is not locked by another process (or by another part of your own code)?  ProcessMon ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645 ) from SysInternals is your friend.  It will record ever I/O to your file along with successes and failures.

Comment: Thats my thinking. Even though it seems to close the file in code, I have a feeling that it doesn't actually do that. I'll give ProcessMon a try. Thanks

Comment: That doesn't help much either I'm afraid. It does not show any activity for the files that I know are being opened and closed by the application, but maybe because I guess because they are on a netowrk drive? I've had to run the processmon as admin on via my remote connection to the Win7 desktop, and whilst I can see calls to the application that opens the problem files, there is no reference to the files that are actually being opened.